# How to insert json into sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, asp.net, json, sql-server-2012

I am inserting data from C# to sql.
I have taken json output in string object.
json is like

```
{'data': '{"Code": "MXXXXX", "Status": "failed"}'}
```

How can I add json data into sql through sp?

Comment: Sql server does not have a json datatype. You can store json values in any string type, like varchar, nvarchar etc'

Comment: If I use as varchar,unable to insert it. insert into table1 (jsonscript) values ({'data': '{"UUI": "MXXXXX", "DialStatus": "answered"}'})

Comment: Are you going to store the value in 2 fields? if yes, deserialize the json and save it in DB. If no, you can use sql parameter to escape the value (and prevent sql injection too)

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 stored procedure for adding Json Data

Below is schema for Table

```
[tbl_activitylog](
    [fk_user_id] [bigint],
    [log_type] [nvarchar](50) ,
    [data] [nvarchar](max) , // json data will be inserted here

Create procedure [dbo].[spp_add_log]
(
    @fk_user_id bigint,
    @log_type nvarchar(50),
    @data nvarchar(MAX)
)
as
begin
   insert into tbl_activitylog (fk_user_id,log_type,data) values  (@fk_user_id,@log_type,@data)
end
```

c# code i have used Linq to entities to access stored procedure

```
List<cls_response_code_data> resp_data_list = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<cls_response_code_data>(
    "spp_add_log @fk_user_id,@log_type,@data",
    new SqlParameter("@fk_user_id", fk_user_id),
    new SqlParameter("@log_type", log_type),
    new SqlParameter("@data", data)
).ToList();
```